# Is it possible to parse a command's arguments automatically?

Tags: command-line, git

I would like to modify the `git clone` command -- such that it use a local cache -- by creating a wrapper that does the following:

1. If a repository doesn't exist in the cache, clone it.
2. Copy it to the desired location.

But how do I parse the [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) command-line arguments to get the value of `repository`? It seems trivial; but I can't find a good solution.

It seems like this is due to a lack of structure in command-line arguments - some could be a switch, some could follow with a value etc. In `git`'s case `<repository>` can be followed by an optional `<directory>` argument, so I can't always go by the last argument. It would have been great if CLI arguments are more structured like dictionary etc.

Is there a way to atleast specify the syntax specified in docs so that, I can get the `repository` argument automatically with tools like `getopts`?

Note: I use multiple tools -- Jenkins, Buildout etc., -- that downloads `git` repositories automatically, using the `git` command; so I thought a wrapper would be best solution.

There are some `git` specific solutions worth checking out like local git server,  URL rewrites etc., as well.

Comment: How about using a git caching proxy such as [Goblet](https://github.com/google/goblet) instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the arguments of the command to search for `@` or `https://` in the command to find the repo, then parse the URL to extract what you need

For example in Python :

```py
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    for i in sys.argv:
        # Do whatever you want (parsing the URL...)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, something like that is worth a try.

Comment: @Nishant This is actually a great idea, feel free to hook me up if you need help

Comment: Sure thank you :-)

Comment: I made that into a bash script. Do have a look :-).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a hacky script: `/usr/local/bin/git` that uses the idea mentioned by Nicholas. It relies on the `--reference-if-able` and `--dissociate` features available in recent versions of Git.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The real executable is located at /usr/local/bin/tig.

command=$1

cache=$HOME/.cache/git/repositories

if [[ ! $command == "clone" ]]; then
    /usr/local/bin/tig "$@"
    exit
fi

caching=false

for argument in "${@:2}"; do
    case $argument in
        --reference | --reference-if-able)
            caching=false
            break
            ;;
        *git@github.com:*)
            caching=true
            [[ $argument == *.git ]] && argument=${argument%.git}
            folder=$cache/$argument
            ;;
    esac
done

if $caching; then
    echo "INFO: Using cache: $folder"
    /usr/local/bin/tig clone \
        --reference-if-able "$folder" --dissociate "${@:2}"
else
    /usr/local/bin/tig "$@"
fi
```

Disclaimer: This is good for development uses only. The best way is to use a Git proxy server like Goblet, as suggested by Stephen.